# How to limit Serilog's output

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

Some of the events that are produced are very large (as in 100k strings).
I'd like to truncate formatted large properties outputs so they don't mess up the sinks (I use Console sinks and Splunk mainly).

For some events I can change the code to disable destructuring.
For others I'm using some form of "auto logging" and can't control the event input parameters.

One of the possible answers I've seen is to use a custom formatter.
That's a very high maintenance and time consuming option because I use multiple sinks so I would need multiple formatters.
Is there a way to truncate properties for all sinks?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there's a way to do what I want using destructuring configuration:

```
new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Destructure.ToMaximumStringLength(100)
    .CreateLogger();
```

will create a Logger that truncates values to 100 characters.

Unfortunately the latest Serilog version (2.10.0) doesn't do that in a very consistent fashion.